# problem using subscripts with sansmath

Tags: equations, subscripts, sans-serif

I have had to (hastily) adapt some Latex to sans serif and I have had some small problems.  I cobbled a preamble together (lifting some stuff from the web) which seems to work, except for some small problems with some characters not decreasing in size in subscripts. The preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage[sfdefault]{classico}
\usepackage[EULERGREEK]{sans math}\sansmath
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xfrac}
```

and the problem arises with text like:

```
\sfrac{k_{f}}{k_{p_{(0 \leq [Q_{A}]_{rel} \leq 1 }}}
```

when this is processed using pdftex the 'less than or equals' signs are disproportionately large and the result is rather unbalanced. The problem is restricted to only a few characters - 'rel', for example, is a subscript on a subscript on subscript and looks fine. Is there a way of getting better scaling of all characters using `\sansmath`  or have I hit a limit in the package? If I have, is there an alternative to `\sansmath`?

Comment: Seems part of the `\scriptscriptstyle` font.  You could always come up with a custom version for `\scriptscriptstyle`, as in `\def\ssleq{\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptscriptstyle\leq$}}` (requires `graphicx` package), using the invocation `$\sfrac{k_{f}}{k_{p_{(0 \ssleq [Q_{A}]_{rel} \ssleq 1 }}}$`.  I didn't use a `\mathrel`, because in `\scriptscriptstyle`, no extra space is added.

Comment: really `{sans math}` with a space?? surely the package is `sansmath` isn't it?

Comment: 'sans math' that is due to the labours of Apple's spell checker - pervasive and sometimes annoying - it pops up sometimes after pasting....

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. The scriptscriptstyle option worked with other symbols, but not \leq (I guess that is where the problem starts). I found a workaround - use \leqslant; that seems to scale OK. I tried a few other characters and some scale while others don't. Seems there is a bug somewhere.......